# Meaning of "Updated?" message in debug mode

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub update_button()
'
' update_button Makro
'

'

Set from = Sheet1
Set towards = Sheet5

With from
    lastRowIndex = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    .Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(lastRowIndex, 4)).Copy
End With
towards.Cells(7, 1).Paste

End Sub
```

This code is supposed to copy cells between A2 and the last row in the first sheet. Then paste it into a specific cell in another sheet. Running this code gives me Runtime error 1004. Application defined or object defined error.

By going into debug mode, and hovering over Cells(2,1), A message comes up saying Cells(2,1)="Updated?". From what I can see, Cells(2,1) is well defined and there should be no issue with it. I am unable to search anything about it given how generic the name is.

Note that I have a non-english version of excel and I have translated a few words to make the code slightly less confusing.

Comment: Yes, I have Module1 and Module2. This code is in module2.

Comment: When I come to think about it, it is not a message, but rather the assignment Cells(2,1)="updated?".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace your instruction

```
.Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(lastRowIndex, 4)).Copy
```

with

```
Range(.Cells(2, 1), .Cells(lastRowIndex, 4)).Copy
```

Comment: Write Application.EnableEvents =False at the beginning of your code and then turn it back on before End sub.You might have some other code at worksheet level which might be causing this message to show up.

Comment: So your answer made the "With from End With" part work. But it stops at towards.Cells(7,1), initially I got the message Cells(7,1)="updated?" when hovering over this. Now it only sais lastRowIndex =56 independent on where I click and hover my mouse.

Comment: what is the content of  from.cells(2,1) ?

Comment: "Updated" is the value held in cell `A2` of the currently `Activesheet`.   @h2so4 said correctly to put the `.` before `Cells(2,1)` as without it Cells references the activesheet and not the sheet used in the `From` keyword.

Comment: The reason for the runtime error is that `.Range` is looking at the `From` worksheet and `Cells` is looking at the `ActiveSheet`.  If these are the same, then no problem but if they're different you're trying to make a range on one sheet using cells from a different sheet.

Comment: Yes, the debugger stops at that line, marking it yellow. I get *Run time errror 438. Object doesn't support this property or method.* I guess this message comes because vba can not paste a selection given a single cell as output.

Comment: Value of Cells(2,1) is updated? Okay, now I understand.